# Error while using sudo apt-get update

Tags: ubuntu, bash

I am using ubuntu 12.04 and while using sudo apt-get update command I get this error:

```
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en     
Fetched 4,683 kB in 1min 14s (62.6 kB/s)                                       
W: Failed to fetch http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart/dists/dist/Release  Unable to find expected entry '10gen/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How do I rectify it?

Comment: Post your /etc/apt/sources.list

Answer (score 0):

This is just a warning. If you want to turn it off, edit your sources.list file to comment out the deb-src line that contains

http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart/dists/dist/Release dist 10gen